# Checking multiple items in a Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to get multiple items checked in a list view I have in my dialog box.

This is the Java code:

```
            String names[] ={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P"};
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);
            alertDialog.setTitle("List");
            ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_list);
            lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);   
            lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            alertDialog.show();
```

It shows the list in my dialog box okay, but when I click/press an item nothing happens. I don't see any tick or anything visually to indicate it's been selected/checked.

Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
```

To :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,     
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_mutiple_choice, names);
```

Comment: Perfect. Using `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Further to this, do you know if it's possible to retain the selections? I find every time the dialog box comes up (triggered by a button press) it doesn't remember which items were selected from the last time it appeared. Thanks

Comment: sorry for late answer , if you want to save which items were selected you need to save position of item selected (in array or something can hold state and position of each item ) then set in again when it reappear (sr for my bad english)

Comment: Thanks - using `alertDialog.setMultiChoiceItems()` I was able to pass in the selected items.